# How to Customized the new order template: Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, order-email

I want to make some text changes in new order template of my Magento so where i can locate the Template file or where i can do this in the admin panel. Also the store logo is not showing in the email how fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add on to Prashant Valanda's answer for your second question of logo.
Navigate to **System configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Invoice and Packing Slip Design** and upload the logo.

Navigate to **System configuration -> General -> Design -> Transactional Emails**.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to **admin > System > Transactional Emails > Add new template**

[image]

As shown in above image select template **New Order**

Now set template for new order from

**admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails -> Order -> New Order Confirmation Template**

select your created template there.

[image]

Comment: Thansk Brother I got it...

Comment: If it helps you mark as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> system->transnational emails

Then click on add new template.
You can see that on template dropdown there are all list of emails. 
Select anyone(**For order select new order and new order for guest**). Make your changes and save it.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Then you can mark it as accepted